# Xenoblade Chronicles 2, all these field screen writing. Overwhelming

Tags: xenoblade-chronicles-2

When traveling to towns in this game, there's an overwhelming number of names describing stores and locations on the screen. Is there a way to disable that? I know the developers team wanted to help people locate places but for people like me, I want to actually experience the game and find those places myself. But most importantly I want to take in the scenery and not be overwhelmed by all these writing overlapping each other, making the field screen clunky and horrible to the eye.

If this question has already been answered, please point me to a source because Google was not helpful.